# Can't load tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help, error

This is what I get on my screen when trying to load tor:

> Tor browser already running but not responding. The old tor browser process must be closed to open a new window.

I click on the message, now it says:

> Your tor browser profile cannot be loaded, may be missing or
>   inaccessible.

Maybe I deleted something by accident?

Comment: What platform are you running on? (Windows, MacOS, Linux?) How are you starting the browser? Clicking on the icon, or from the command line? Have you just updated the browser or is this a completely fresh install? Please edit the question with as much information as possible.